# Population Differential Equation with partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Im trying to solve the following differential equation:
$\frac{dP}{dt} = 8P-(6+ \frac{P}{2500})P$.

I think this might be possible using partial fractions somehow but my attempt so far is:

$$\begin{align}\frac{dP}{dt} &= 2P- \frac{P^2}{2500} \\
\frac{dP}{2P + \frac{P^2}{2500}} &= t+c \\
\ln\left|2P + \frac{P^2}{2500}\right| &= t+c
\end{align}$$ 
- this is about as far as i can get

Any help will be appreciated

edit: I tried a partial fractions approach but didn't get very far

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y - \frac{y^2}{2500}$$

Comment: Are you sure the equation you typed is correct?  If so the simplification should be $\frac{dP}{dt} = 8P - 6P^{2} - \frac{P^{2}}{2500}$ not $\frac{dP}{dt} = 2P+ \frac{P^2}{2500}$.

Comment: made the edit, you were correct, thank you

Comment: Even with that there you should still have $- \frac{P^{2}}{2500}$ in your simplification and you cannot integrate what you have get a natural log.

Comment: Best of luck in your future career.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the attempted solution: (1) The coefficients of $P, P^2$ in the simplification of the given differential equation are wrong. (2) The integration of the differential in $dP$ is incorrect.

In any case, we can write the differential equation in the form
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = r P + s P^2$$
for some constants $r, s$, and integrating gives
$$\int \frac{dP}{r P + s P^2} = \int dt .$$

To apply the method of partial fractions, we factor the denominator: $r P + s P^2 = P (r + s P)$. Then, (for $r \neq 0$) we can write the integrand of the integral w.r.t. $dP$ as
$$\frac{1}{r P + s P^2} = \frac{A}{P} + \frac{B}{r + sP}$$
for constants $A, B$ we can find explicitly in terms of $r, s$.

Comment: I did make some edits to my formatting, i must have copied my attempt incorrectly. thanks for the reply, i will try this method and see how i go

Comment: so once i solve for constants $A,B$ in terms of $r,s$ (which in this case i found were 2 and $\frac{-1}{2500}$ respectively), this expression with the partial fractions (once i integrate it) is equivalent to the integral on the right hand side correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the integral equation says.